# How do I link my check_box filter with my search form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a search form that searches through posts but I want users to be able to filter these searches based on various attributes. How do I link the checkbox filters to the search? I am using sunspot gem to filter through the posts.

This is post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user


    searchable do
        text :details
        text :title
    end


end
```

This is show.html.erb in posts folder

```
<div class = "container">
  <% @posts.each do |x| %>
    <div class="fb" id="download">
      <div class="post">
           <div class="top">
             <div class="name">
               <strong><a href="#"><span class="text-name"><%= x.title %></span></a></strong>
              </div>
            </div>
            <span class="text-message"><%= x.details %></span><br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This is show function in my posts controller

```
def show 
    @search = Post.search do
      fulltext params[:search]
    end
    @posts = @search.results
  end
```

And this is the search form in my application.html.erb

```
<% if current_user.profile %>
                    <li><%= form_tag user_post_path(user_id: current_user.id), :method => :get do %>
                    <p>
                    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], autocomplete: "off", placeholder: "Try \"Tennis\"" %>
                    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    <% end %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Create Post", new_user_post_path(user_id: current_user.id), class: "linkfocus"%></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Profile", user_path(id:current_user.id), class: "linkfocus"%></li>
<% else %>
```